# radare2 convenience variables

Tags: radare2

gdb allows setting arbitrary convenience variables:

```
set $a = "test"
set $b = 3
p $a # => "test"
p $b # => 3
```

Is there a way to do something similar in radare2? I'd like to be able to e.g.:

```
set $len = 0x100
px `$len` # => does px 0x100
echo $len # => echos 0x100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in r2 there's the concept of 'flags' which is basically a way to associate a name to a number.

So in that case you do:

```
f test = 0x100
px test
```